# Comparing two text files and only keeping unique values

Tags: powershell

All,

I am VERY new to powershell and am attempting to write a script and have run into an issue.

I currently have two text files. For argument sake the first can be called required.txt and the second can be called exist.txt.

I have a script which queries a server and determines a list of all existing groups and writes these to a text file. At the same time the customer has a list of new groups they wish to create. I want to compare the new list (required.txt) with the existing list (exist.txt) and anything which doesn't exist be piped out to a new text file which is then picked up and imported using another process.

I've got the scripting done to gather the list from the server I just need to know how to do the comparison between the existing and required.

Any suggestions welcome.

Richard

Comment: Not to worry I managed to do what I wanted using the following:

`$DeploymentGroupList = get-content $Inputfile
$DeploymentGroupList += Get-Content $workingfile
$DeploymentGroupList = $DeploymentGroupList | Sort Name
$Exceptions = Get-Content $workingfile
$List = @()
foreach ($DeploymentGroup in $DeploymentGroupList){
 if($Exceptions -contains $DeploymentGroup){
  #Skip
 }
 else{
  $List += $DeploymentGroup
 }
}
# Creating a final list of groups to be imported
$List > $FinalGroups`

Comment: you should provide the solution as an answer to the question please.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use as much variables :

```
$FinalGroups=Compare-Object (get-content .\required.txt) (get-content .\existing.txt) |
    where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} |
    select -ExpandProperty inputObject |
    sort
```